# Determine pairs that make two systems of linear equations equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any clean and pretty way to determine all pairs $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$ that make the following systems of linear equations equivalent:
$$
S :\left\{
\begin{array}{l} x+ay+z+t=0 \\  2x-y+bz-t=0 \end{array}\right.
\quad S' :\left\{
\begin{array}{l} bx+4z=0 \\  ax-2y+(b-1)z-2t=0 \end{array}\right.
$$
I've tried to discuss the system with equations from $S$ and $S'$ but this is infuriating. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I *know* that I've seen exactly this before ...

Comment: I just searched the site and haven't found anything similar

Comment: If I remember correctly, a more or less similar question appeared a few days ago, but was quickly deleted after being posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient matrices for the two systems of equations are
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&a&1&1\\
2&-1&b&-1
\end{pmatrix},
\ B=\begin{pmatrix}
b&0&4&0\\
a&-2&b-1&-2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to see that the two rows of $A$ are linearly independent and the two rows of $B$ are also linearly independent, regardless of the values of $a$ and $b$. Therefore, the two systems of equations are equivalent if and only if the two rows in $B$ lie inside the row space of $A$. Now the first row of $B$ is a linear combination of the two rows of $A$ if and only if every $3\times3$ submatrix of
$$
C=\begin{pmatrix}
1&a&1&1\\
2&-1&b&-1\\
b&0&4&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has zero determinant. By deleting the third column of $C$, the determinant vanishes if and only if $a=1$. For this $a$, the other three determinants (obtained by deleting resp. the 1st, 2nd and 4th column of $C$) are $0$ and $\pm(b-3)(b+4)$. Hence they are all zero if and only if $b=3$ or $b=-4$. Finally, for these $a,b$, the second row of $B$ is equal to $(-1,1)A$. Hence we conclude that $S$ and $S'$ are equivalent if $a=1$ and $b=3$ or $-4$.

Answer (score 1):

By adding and subtracting, $S$ is equivalent to $$S'':\begin{cases}3x+(a-1)y+(b+1)z=0\\x-(a+1)y+(b-1)z-2t=0.\end{cases}$$
Comparing witth $S'$ strongly suggests $a=1$, $b=3$.
Can you see why $S_1$ and $S_2$ are *not* equivalent for any other choice?

Answer (score 0):

For a given $(a,b)$, you have two equations in four unknowns $x,y,z,t$, so you should be able to express any two in terms of the other two.  Working with $S'$ we note that $y$ and $t$ do not occur in the first, so let's solve for $y,z$.  The first gives $z=-\frac b4 x$.  The second gives $y=\frac 12(ax+(b-1)z)-2t)=\frac 12((a-\frac {-b(b-1)}4)x-2t)$.  Now solve the first set for $y,z$ the same way and equate the coefficients.  The first thing to notice is that the coefficient linking $y$ and $t$ is $-1$, so you must have $a=1$ in $S$.  That just leaves $b$.